# My code is not working ?python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n=int(input())
c={}
for i in range(n):
    name=str(input())
    c[name]=list(input().split())
print(c)
query=input()
query_scores=c[query]
print(sum(query_scores))
```

The `sum` function is not working. It shows:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: `query_scores=c[query]`  - those are strings. how do you sum up strings? `query_scores=map(int,c[query])` _might_ work, if the contained list only contains numbers that can be converted to int - else it will throw you ValueErrors - I feel as if hackerrank related questions provide > 80% of the bad questions coming in ...

Comment: Happy Coding. 
Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Read,live and breathe [how to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) as well - and start using a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

From `sum`'s description:

> Sums start and the items of an iterable from left to right and returns
>   the total. start defaults to 0. The iterable’s items are normally
>   numbers, and the start value is not allowed to be a string.

Since the sum starts to 0 (by default), you need to cast the elements you want to sum to something that can be added to 0. strings cannot. You need to do something like this:

```
print(sum(int(x) for x in query_scores))
```

or, if you want to use floating numbers,

```
print(sum(float(x) for x in query_scores))
```

Comment: do not encourage bad questions

Comment: I understand the first part of your comment and I apologise for that (and will delete the answer if that's better), but how does my answer not address the question?

Comment: Sorry, did not read far enough. It does address the problem. -1 to +0 but still, please dont answer bad questions. The Q was already answered in the comment about 4 minutes before your post, but I guess you were already writing your answer up and editing it at that point so you did not see that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the list items into any numeric type. The split function returns the string type and you are performing the sum in the str type

```
c[name]=list(input().split())
```

Can be changed into

```
c[name] = [ int(i) for i in input().split()]
```